# From a deployment and OPS perspective, should a S/MIME signing and encryption key have different expiration dates?

Tags: email, mobile, smime

Assuming the client supports different keys, what is some rationale that should be considered for signing and encryption keys?

The encryption key

- needs to be present on each device that is used to read email
- all those copies means it has a greater risk of getting lost or stolen on mobile devices (and therefore should be revoked)

The signing key

- can be device-specific
- Since it has a long lasting lifetime (2-4 years), it can be revoked when a device is stolen.

Therefore a fewer subset of messages will have their integrity called into question

Is this valid thinking? What are some other perspectives?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the lifetime of a key should be determined by its strength, according to both its keysize, and to the likelihood of reports of weaknesses in the algoritm used to create the keys.

According to [Technet.com](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrteam/archive/2009/06/12/recommendations-for-pki-key-lengths-and-validity-periods-with-configuration-manager.aspx) in 2009, regarding how long RSA suggest the validity period of a certificate should be, based on how long it would take an adversary to compromise a key, based on the size of the key alone.

```
Key length of 1024:  Validity period = not greater than 6-12 months
Key length of 2048:  Validity period = not greater than 2 years
Key length of 4096:  Validity period = not greater than 16 years
```

Also, you cannot have a certificate signed by a CA have a validity period longer than that of the CA itself.